# How negate the condition in CSS

Tags: html, css

Below is my code, I am naive in HTML/CSS, Let me know if I missed any thing here.

```css
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a id="btn-other-1" href="#">
    <!–- I do not want apply css for this anchor tag because it has i inside –->
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span> Other stuff-1? </span>
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a id="btn-other-2" href="#">
    <span> Other stuff-2 </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

The problem is that the given css code applies to all anchor tag `<a>` which is inside `<li>` but I don't want to apply it on anchor tag `<a>` which has `<i>` tag inside.

How to do I do that in CSS?

Comment: You like to use jQuery for this...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: I prefer solution using CSS.

Comment: You can give class in a tag which has `i` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated by kravisingh, no parent selector in CSS for now.

Without changing your HTML, there's a workaround for your example: you can **apply padding to children** of link and the good news is - in your example - you can easily distinguish in pure CSS the children in both cases.

I used `:only-child` to select a span element without any sibling (thus no i element before or after), demonstrated below.
You also have in your toolbox:

- `:first-child` (if `span` matches then it means there is no `i` before it)
- `:last-child`
- `+` the adjacent sibling (`i + a { /* */ }` is `a` strictly following an `i`?)
- `~` the general sibling (`i ~ a { /* */ }` is `a` following an `i`, maybe with other elements in-between?)
- and `:not()` (ex: `span:not(:only-child)`: `span` elements that aren't alone in their parent element, may be preceded or followed by other `span` or `i` or …)

Notes:

- This workaround won't work for all styles and cases :/
- It's easier to add a class on parent (see Amit's answer) but there are cases where you can't modify markup or where a CSS solution is easier than modifying the back/front-end functions that generates markup (though it's then harder to maintain code IMHO)

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/RLPgZr?editors=1000)**

```css
/* CSS from question (example #1) */
.on-link > li > a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

/* Example #2 */

/* Applies to i+span */
.on-children i {
  /*padding: 3px 0 3px 5px;*/
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.on-children i + span {
  /*padding: 3px 5px 3px 0;*/
  background-color: pink;
}

/* Applies to any span without an icon  (after or before)
Note: :first-child would allow for an icon at the end of the link */
.on-children span:only-child {
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background-color: tomato;
}

/* Demo */
.on-children i:before {
  content: 'i ';
}
```

```html
<h1>Styles link (original styles from OP)</h1> 
<ul class="on-link">
  <li>
      <a id="btn-other-1" href="#">            <!–- I do not want apply css for this anchor tag because it has i inside –->
          <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true">
          </i><span>Other stuff-1? </span>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a id="btn-other-2" href="#">
          <span>Other stuff-2</span>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<hr>

<h1>Styles children of link (my answer)</h1>
<ul class="on-children">
  <li>
      <a id="btn-other-1" href="#">            <!–- I do not want apply css for this anchor tag because it has i inside –->
          <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Other stuff-1?</span>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a id="btn-other-2" href="#">
          <span>Other stuff-2</span>
      </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

There is no any way in `css` to apply a selection to their parent. So you must need to use `jquery` or `javascript` for this.

```
$('.dropdown-menu a i').parent().css('padding','0');
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: padding : unset is better. 0 means that it will stick to the borders

Answer (score 0):

If there was in a first `li` than you can use `:first-child`  selector

```
.dropdown-menu > li:first-child > a {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Or you can use `id` or `class` name of `a` tag

```
<li>
    <a id="btn-other-1" href="#" class="icon">            <!–- I do not want apply css for this anchor tag because it has i inside –->
        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>   
        <span> Other stuff-1? </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="btn-other-2" href="#">
        <span> Other stuff-2 </span>
    </a>
</li>

.dropdown-menu > li > a:not(.icon) {
      padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Manish, There are multiple tags not just two and they are at many places.

Answer (score 0):

Check for combinators here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors, but i don't think there will a direct combinator available.

The easiest option would be assign a dummy classname to anchor with i tag, and a different to anchor without i tag.

```
<li>
    <a id="btn-other-1" href="#" class="itag">            <!–- I do not want apply css for this anchor tag because it has i inside –->
        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>   
        <span> Other stuff-1? </span>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="btn-other-2" href="#" class="noitag">
        <span> Other stuff-2 </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Then use it like.

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a.noitag {
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```